# Regex - accept only numbers between 4 to 12 (shouldnot accept anything else)

Tags: javascript

textbox should accept only 2 digits.It should accept only numbers between 4 to 12. suppose if  u enter 1,2,3, it should not allow,similarly if u enter more than 12 it should not allow

Comment: You do not need regexp for that. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp and check the range

Comment: if your textarea contains not only digits, you can use simple regex like [0-9]{0,1}, and then check for range as @cheery wrote

Answer (score 1):

in case you want the regex,

```
([4-9]|1[0-2])
```

Comment: actually, `([^\d][4-9]|1[0-2])`, so it won't take "4" from "24". but still get "4" from "42", so parseInt would work better